# Python connect to Hadoop using Hive with Kerberos authentication

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, kerberos, hiveql

I am trying to connect python to **Hadoop using Hive** using Kerberos. Tried various sources but failed in connecting

```
 import pyhs2
conn_config = {'krb_host': 'hostname', 'krb_service': 'hive'}
pyhs2.connect(host='hostname',
                   port=10000,
                   authMechanism="KERBEROS",
                   password="********",
                  user='hostname@SCGLOBALUAT.ADUAT.SCOTIACAPITAL.COM')
```

Error Encountered:

```
authMechanism="KERBEROS") as conn:
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyhs2\__init__.py", line 7, in connect
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyhs2\connections.py", line 46, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyhs2\cloudera\thrift_sasl.py", line 66, in open
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2
```

can please somebody help me to give clear instructions to connect python to **Hadoop using Hive with Kerberos** Ticket

Comment: @kecso can you help me to resolve this issue. Your help is much appreciated